# Simplify expression after substitution

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I tried to substitue variable x of one equation with another variable `z` (`z=nx/(nx+m)`). See as follow:

```
Solve[z == n*x/(n*x + m), x]
```

> ```
> x -> -((m z)/(n (-1 + z)))
> ```

Then:

```
PDF[FRatioDistribution[n, m], x] /. x -> -((m z)/(n (-1 + z)))
```

> ```
>  (m^(m/2) n^(n/2) (-((m z)/(n (-1 + z))))^(-1 + n/2) (m - (m z)/(-1 + z))^(1/2 
>   (-m - n)))/Beta[n/2, m/2]
> ```

How can I collect the term `z` and `1-z` together? Factually, if collecting the results by `` `z and ``1-z`, it can be very simple (that is Beta distribution). Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just `FullSimplify[..., Assumptions -> {n > 0, m > 0}]`

Comment: Thaks your reply. it helps.

Comment: @ybeltukov answer?

Answer (score 2):

`FullSimplify` with `Assumptions` makes what you want

```
FullSimplify[PDF[FRatioDistribution[n, m], x] /. x -> -((m z)/(n (-1 + z))), 
  Assumptions -> {n > 0, m > 0}]
```

> ```
> (n (1 - z)^(1 + m/2) z^(-1 + n/2))/(m Beta[n/2, m/2])
> ```